# connecting two values into dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i've been trying to connect the two data "product_id" and "status" , because later i wanted to make a condition "only search for product that has status of 32"

```
[
{"_id":"62eaa99b014c9bb30203e48a","amount":{"product":291000,"shipping":75000,"admin_fee":4500,"order_voucher_deduction":0,"transaction_voucher_deduction":0,"total":366000,"paid":366000},"status":32,"items":[{"_id":"62eaa99b014c9bb30203e48d","earning":80400,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Black"},{"name":"size","value":"38"}],"marketplace_price":65100,"product_price":62000,"reseller_price":145500,"product_id":227991,"name":"OCL Shoes heels Women R03","sku_id":890512,"internal_markup":3100,"weight":500,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659384575578.jpeg","quantity":1,"supplier_price":60140},{"_id":"62eaa99b014c9bb30203e48e","earning":80400,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Coklat"},{"name":"size","value":"37"}],"marketplace_price":65100,"product_price":62000,"reseller_price":145500,"product_id":227991,"name":"OCL Shoes heels Women R03","sku_id":890507,"internal_markup":3100,"weight":500,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659384575576.jpeg","quantity":1,"supplier_price":60140}],"created_at":"2022-08-03T17:00:11.438Z"},
{"_id":"62eaaa03014c9bb30203e778","amount":{"product":294000,"shipping":51000,"admin_fee":8000,"order_voucher_deduction":0,"transaction_voucher_deduction":10500,"total":345000,"paid":334500},"status":6,"items":[{"_id":"62eaaa03014c9bb30203e77c","earning":84000,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Black white"},{"name":"size","value":"40"}],"marketplace_price":210000,"product_price":200000,"reseller_price":294000,"product_id":102292,"name":"Shoes Reebok 22 Grade Original","sku_id":307466,"internal_markup":10000,"weight":700,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659381767432.jpeg","quantity":1,"supplier_price":194000}],"created_at":"2022-08-03T17:01:55.053Z"},
{"_id":"62eaaa0e014c9bb30203e7eb","amount":{"product":66000,"shipping":18000,"admin_fee":1500,"order_voucher_deduction":0,"transaction_voucher_deduction":0,"total":84000,"paid":84000},"status":6,"items":[{"_id":"62eaaa0e014c9bb30203e7ee","earning":11237,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Black"},{"name":"size","value":"All Size Fit To Xl"}],"marketplace_price":54763,"product_price":52155,"reseller_price":66000,"product_id":176870,"name":"GHB Hoodie Men Women ESOBOY - Disc up to 10%","sku_id":632791,"internal_markup":2608,"weight":500,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659382700813.png","quantity":1,"supplier_price":50590}],"created_at":"2022-08-03T17:02:06.464Z"}]
```

I've been searching and trying and i thought "might be zip is possible?" or i don't know maybe there are more better ways to do it ?
I'm literally still newbie and learning so sorry if the question is seems too dumb..

At first i tried to show the data from the `datasetjson["items"][0][0]["product_id"]` and also `datasetjson["status"][0]` manually, but if there are hundreds, how to zip with hundreds of records?

[image]

##update

What I'm trying to achieve is that :

```
|      product_id     | Count_Status_32  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          227991     |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          102292     |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          176870     |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Since there are 2 items in that list, and having the same status, so the count will be 2, because their status is 32
[image]

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by saying `connect`?
Or drop an example of the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @NoobVB i already updated it, thankyou for the suggestions , hope it helps to explain more ..

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Title: **"Then one Noob tries to help another Noob"** :)

it was a challenge for me, as I am not very familiar with jason structures,
but I have managed to do it only in such a way and I am sure it is not the best one:

```
data = [
{"_id":"62eaa99b014c9bb30203e48a","amount":{"product":291000,"shipping":75000,"admin_fee":4500,"order_voucher_deduction":0,"transaction_voucher_deduction":0,"total":366000,"paid":366000},"status":32,"items":[{"_id":"62eaa99b014c9bb30203e48d","earning":80400,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Black"},{"name":"size","value":"38"}],"marketplace_price":65100,"product_price":62000,"reseller_price":145500,"product_id":227991,"name":"OCL Shoes heels Women R03","sku_id":890512,"internal_markup":3100,"weight":500,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659384575578.jpeg","quantity":1,"supplier_price":60140},{"_id":"62eaa99b014c9bb30203e48e","earning":80400,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Coklat"},{"name":"size","value":"37"}],"marketplace_price":65100,"product_price":62000,"reseller_price":145500,"product_id":227991,"name":"OCL Shoes heels Women R03","sku_id":890507,"internal_markup":3100,"weight":500,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659384575576.jpeg","quantity":1,"supplier_price":60140}],"created_at":"2022-08-03T17:00:11.438Z"},
{"_id":"62eaaa03014c9bb30203e778","amount":{"product":294000,"shipping":51000,"admin_fee":8000,"order_voucher_deduction":0,"transaction_voucher_deduction":10500,"total":345000,"paid":334500},"status":6,"items":[{"_id":"62eaaa03014c9bb30203e77c","earning":84000,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Black white"},{"name":"size","value":"40"}],"marketplace_price":210000,"product_price":200000,"reseller_price":294000,"product_id":102292,"name":"Shoes Reebok 22 Grade Original","sku_id":307466,"internal_markup":10000,"weight":700,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659381767432.jpeg","quantity":1,"supplier_price":194000}],"created_at":"2022-08-03T17:01:55.053Z"},
{"_id":"62eaaa0e014c9bb30203e7eb","amount":{"product":66000,"shipping":18000,"admin_fee":1500,"order_voucher_deduction":0,"transaction_voucher_deduction":0,"total":84000,"paid":84000},"status":6,"items":[{"_id":"62eaaa0e014c9bb30203e7ee","earning":11237,"variants":[{"name":"color","value":"Black"},{"name":"size","value":"All Size Fit To Xl"}],"marketplace_price":54763,"product_price":52155,"reseller_price":66000,"product_id":176870,"name":"GHB Hoodie Men Women ESOBOY - Disc up to 10%","sku_id":632791,"internal_markup":2608,"weight":500,"image":"https://product-asset.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1659382700813.png","quantity":1,"supplier_price":50590}],"created_at":"2022-08-03T17:02:06.464Z"}
]

datasetjson = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(datasetjson)
                       _id  status  ... amount.total amount.paid
0  62eaa99b014c9bb30203e48a      32  ...       366000      366000
1  62eaaa03014c9bb30203e778       6  ...       345000      334500
2  62eaaa0e014c9bb30203e7eb       6  ...        84000       84000

# as jasondata has list of other dictionaries, I would flatten it (extract columns) from dicts in the list
# we will need to pass the list of columns for parameter `meta`
col_meta = [[s for s in c.split(".")] for c in datasetjson.columns] # creates list of column names

df1 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=[["items"]], meta=col_meta, meta_prefix="item_") # extracting columns using col_meta list

# at last, grouping by product_id and counting item_status using lambda function
df2 = df1.groupby('product_id')['item_status'].apply(lambda x: (x == 32).sum()).reset_index(name='Count_Status_32')
```

finally!

```
print(df2)
  product_id  Count_Status_32
0      102292                0
1      176870                0
2      227991                2
```